# Create maven artifact in STS (eclipse)

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven

I have a multi-module project that I am developing in STS 3.8.4 (eclipse neon.3).
I have 4 projects so far. A, B, C. A is the parent. B & C. A uses pom packaging. C has a dependency on B. I am also running an Apache Archiva repository. I have successfully deployed all 3 modules to Archiva with "mvn deploy". In the project for Module C, B is shown in the Maven Dependencies a B rather than B-x.y.jar. In Build Path, Libraries, B show sub-entries of
Access Rules
Native Library Location

other jar files also show
Source attachment
Javadoc Location
External Annotations

In module C, the dependencies from module B are not found.

A/pom.xml includes

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<name>A/name>
<groupId>project</groupId>
<artifactId>A</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

...

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/repository/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>internal</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/repository/internal/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/repository/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>internal</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/repository/internal/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

B/pom.xml includes

```
    <parent>
    <relativePath>../A/pom.xml</relativePath>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<name>B</name>
<artifactId>B</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

...

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/repository/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>internal</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/repository/internal/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/repository/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>internal</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/repository/internal/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

C/pom.xml includes

```
<parent>
    <relativePath>../A/pom.xml</relativePath>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<name>C</name>
<artifactId>C</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>project</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

...

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/repository/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>internal</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/repository/internal/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/repository/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>internal</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/repository/internal/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

In addition, I notice that a "mvn package" does not include the target classes in the resultant jar file. It only includes the dependent jar files. Here's the  section of B/pom.xml.

```
<build>
    <plugins> 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>
```

Comment: I think I found the problem with the classes not showing up. They are in BOOT-INF/classes. That, of course, is where Spring Boot places it's classes for jar packaging. Unfortunately, that makes it hard to include as a subproject. BTW, Spring Boot was specified as the parent of project A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing all the spring boot stuff from the pom. I got the classes moved out of BOOT-INF/classes. I had to add a bunch more plugins from the effective pom to the real pom so I could remove the spring-boot-maven-plugin.

I believe this also fixed the problems I had with resolving the classes of the project B in project C.

The problem of not seeing B-x.y.jar in the maven dependencies for project C is just the way eclipse works. The icon next to the entry is a folder icon rather than a jar icon. I guess this just means that eclipse is resolving this as a folder in it's project hierarchy, rather than as a maven jar.